# sorting bootstrap modal-body elements in Javascript/Jquery when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am working on the fiddle in which I want to sort multiple rows (**Row1 having def and Assign a Computer Section, Row2 having abc and Assign a Computer Section, etc**) coming from Bootstrap Modal.

At this moment, the rows are not sorted in the modal. The HTML/Bootstrap code which I have used in order to create the modal is :

```
<div class="row-computerlabel form-group clearfix">
   <div class="editcomputerlabel col-sm-5">abc</div>
   <div class="assigncomputerlabel col-sm-5">
      <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick computerlabelscomputerselector">
         <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Assign a computer"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Assign a computer</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button>
         <div class="dropdown-menu open">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu"></ul>
         </div>
         <select class="computerlabelscomputerselector selectpicker" multiple="" title="Assign a computer" tabindex="-98"></select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="deletecomputerlabel col-sm-2"><button class="btn btn-link btn-delete" data-task="deletelabel" title="Delete group" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></div>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what plain Javascript or Jquery code I need to add above so that all the contents in the Bootstrap Modal get sorted **meaning abc, def, jkl text should show up first with their assigned computers** in the fiddle when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sort function of JavaScript.

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var rowComputer = $('.row-computerlabel');

    rowComputer.sort(function(a,b){
        var label1 = $(a).children('.editcomputerlabel').text();
        var label2 = $(b).children('.editcomputerlabel').text();
            return label1 >= label2;
    });
    rowComputer.appendTo('#computerlabeltable');
});
```

This piece of code is really simple. You have in the `rowComputer` variable all your rows.

You apply the sort function on your array and you need to specify the condition of your sorting (here it needs to be sorted alphabetically).

Finally, you append your array containing your rows in the div englobing all yours rows.

**jsFiddle**

Here is a jFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/Lqam4g2u/

Comment: I have edited the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lqam4g2u/2/ Is it should be like this as it has 3 child elements ?

Comment: Currently you have used only `editcomputerlabel` only.

Comment: Sorry John, I couldn't answer you. No need, the sort function works with 2 arguments. If you have 2 elements to compare or 100, it will works. And, I used editcomputerlabel because that's what you want to compare. For each row-computer-label, the sort function takes their editcomputerlabel class to sort them.